# fadeOut work immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some div in my page that when an user drags one of them the div would fade out.It's work but div fadeout after 6 second immediately.

```
$(function(){
    $( ".comment-list.clearfix" ).draggable({axis: "x"},{
      start: function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(6000);
      },
    });
});
```

Comment: use `delay()` to delay your `fadeOut` effect, like `$(this).delay(500).fadeOut(6000);`

Comment: *"but div fadeout after 6 second immediately..."* Well, which is it? After six seconds, or immediately?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I mean div's opacity doesn't down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) for delay like,

```
start: function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
       $this.fadeOut(6000);
    },5000); // 5 seconds timeout, for example
}
```

or use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) like,

```
start: function() {
    $(this).delay(5000) // 5 seconds delay, for example
           .fadeOut(6000);
}
```

*Note: You can change delay interval, as you required.*

Comment: Why a five second delay? The only time period given in the question is six.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just used for example.